# Android App showing multiple screen and lagging activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am facing the following issue and am unable to find the solution to it.

All the activities/fragments have UI glitches only on specific devices(android version <Android Version 9 (Mi A1)>).

Whenever a UI is scrolled or navigated to a different screen, patchy UI glitches will be leftover on the screen.

Adding screenshot and video for reference.

Any help would be appriciated!

[image]

[Screen recording for full detail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ByRm2kCBTeAD4WRSVLDkELT6I_dqvIQ5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What about the code?

Comment: It's working perfectly on other devices, but some devices have this issue. also i'm getting multiple repeated logs in logcat for ex- libPowerHal: [perfScnDumpAll] scn:76 user_name:mtkpower@1.0-se pid:675 tid:0 state:0 type:1 hdl:136 hint:0